# AlphaFS Overcoming 260 character path limit

Tags: excel, powershell, dll

Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 
260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I still need to work with these objects, and renaming to shorten the names is not an option, so is there anyway of actually working with objects whos path is too long for Get-ChildItem to deal with?

I then found out about an open source .NET library called AlphaFS that overcomes these limits. How can I replace my script  with AlphaFS?

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OOXML.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll")

$wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions");
$wr = $ws.CreateRow(0);



$wr.createCell(0).setCellValue("Folder Path");
$wr.createCell(1).setCellValue("Users/Groups");
$wr.createCell(2).setCellValue("Permissions");
$wr.createCell(3).setCellValue("AccessControlType");
$wr.createCell(4).setCellValue("Permissions Inherited")



$dirToAudit = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Inetpub" -recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

$maxRow = 1048576
$intRow = 1
$intNextSheet = 2

foreach ($dir in $dirToAudit)
{
    $colACL = Get-Acl -Path $dir.FullName

    foreach ($acl in $colACL)
    {
        $fileNameRow = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
        $fileNameRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue($dir.FullName)
        $intRow++

        if ($intRow -eq $maxRow)
        {
            $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions" + $intNextSheet);
            $intNextSheet++
            $intRow = 0
        }

        foreach ($accessRight in $acl.Access)
        {
            $values = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
            $values.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.IdentityReference).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.FileSystemRights).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.AccessControlType).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue($($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected).ToString())
            $intRow++

            if ($intRow -eq $maxRow)
            {
                $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions" + $intNextSheet);
                $intNextSheet++
                $intRow = 0
            }
        }
    }

}
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream("C:\export\test.xlsx",[System.IO.FileMode]'Create',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Write')
$wb.Write($fs);
$fs.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried [`subst`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx) for mapping long paths as virtual drives?

Comment: No I haven't tried something like that before

Comment: In this case `mklink` seems a better fit then `subst`. You'll run out of drives using `subst`:)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers how can I do that? please clarify

Comment: @Arbelac - that was a direct comment on the subst comment. I have now just taken a closer look at your script and if you want to start from a root folder like c:\inetpub, mklink (or subst) is not an option. Using mklink you could create a new "root" folder pointing to another (too) deep path but you can't shorten a complete folder structure. It's more like shortening `c:\inetpub\my\too\long\folder` to `c:\folder` but that way you don't enumerate `c:\inetpub\my\too\long\folder2`

Comment: [This](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/07/24/jaap-brassers-favorite-powershell-tips-and-tricks/) is a better fit for your problem

Comment: thanks how do I use Get-LongPathName function insteaf of Get-Childitem ? Could you give an example how to use it?

Comment: Download the script, place it in a folder of your likings and dot source it in your actual script *(. <path_to_script\Get-LongPathName.ps1)*

Comment: how can I adapted it with my script? could you please give me detail informations?